OS randomly stopped working, And now i cant seem to get a new install to work
After not looking at the PC for like half an hour with nothing open, i return to see the background set to pure blue and no actions working, When i force restarted it no longer booted, this also applied to a second unmounted disk which had a test install of mint.
I had Kubuntu on a live usb and installed that on the empty disk, except it doesnt work. For some reason i cannot run commands like apt-add-repository, it just hangs untill it times out, preventing me from reinstalling my programs. Some actions seem slow in general, and certain web pages like youtube randomly hang and i need to keep refreshing the page.
Then i tried intalling Mint again but i cant do that at all, it just hangs after the screen with the option for the additional drivers.
Any idea what i should do? The original install was plain ubuntu, but that wayland thing makes it useless from the start so id have to install the older version 22 where i can still disable it, which has other bugs that Kubuntu seemed to avoid.

These look like classic symptoms of a hardware fault.
